# How to pretty-print inlined variables when formatting strings

Tags: rust, rust-clippy

Normally one can print strings the following way: `println!("{:#?}", foo)` where the `{:#?}` syntax will make a pretty-print of the value. But I know it's also possible to inline the variable directly in the string between the curly braces, instead of listing it as a second argument to the macro, like so: `println!("{foo}")`.

My question is - can I combine the pretty-print syntax and inlining the variable in the string?

I found out about the shorthand syntax from [clippy's docs](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#uninlined_format_args), but I couldn't find (or understand) how to combine it with pretty-print (if it's at all possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply place the variable name before the colon:

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo = 3;
    println!("{foo:#?}");
}
```

Note:

- `:#?` is pretty-printed `Debug` output
- `:?` is normal `Debug` output
- no modifier is `Display` output

[`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) is for user-facing output

[`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) is for output when debugging, also used for panic messages